# How to update a single bit of a binary number as toggle?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
// numbers
+---------+------------+
|    id   |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |   bit(10)  |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1001100111 |
| 2       | 0111000101 |
| 3       | 0001101010 |
| 4       | 1111111011 |
+---------+------------+
```

I'm trying to change *(toggle)* the value of seventh digit *(right to left)*. So focus on this digit:

```
// for example
1001100111
  ^ seventh digit (rtl)
```

And this is expected result:

```
// new_numbers
+---------+------------+
|    id   |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |   bit(10)  |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1011100111 |
| 2       | 0101000101 |
| 3       | 0011101010 |
| 4       | 1101111011 |
+---------+------------+
```

---

I can update seventh digit like

```
// set it to zero
UPDATE numbers SET numb = numb & b'1110111111';
```

But actually I need to toggle it.

- if it is `0` then set it `1`
- if it is `1` then set it `0`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flipping a bit is done by XOR `^` operation with a mask that has `1`s in positions that you would like to toggle.

This works because the truth table of XOR looks like this:

```
  A: 0 0 1 1
  B: 0 1 0 1
A^B: 0 1 1 0
```

Note the columns where `B` is `1`: when the corresponding bit in `A` is zero, the result is one, and vice versa.

Togging seventh bit is done like this:

```
UPDATE numbers SET numb = numb ^ b'0001000000';
```

Comment: I'm wonder .. What's your expertise? You have a gold badge in C++, C#, IOS and .. **except** MySQL. But you answer MySQL's questions as an expert. Good for you.

Comment: @stack Honestly, I didn't know MySQL supported bit operators until I saw your other question this morning. I looked up the manual, and saw that MySQL uses the same operators as C, C++, C#, Java, and many other languages. Working with bits is a portable skill, because the operations are always the same. All you need to do is look up the syntax in your particular language.

Comment: I'm impressed ..! This kind of people *(like you)* are always successful. I don't know how old you are or what's your sex .. All I know about you: you are really clever and fast. Being like you is one of my dreams `:-)`. Thank you again for all your helps.

Comment: To be honest, I'm embarrassed to ping you again. But I have a pretty similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215218/flipping-the-value-of-bit-data-type). Please if you have some free time, take a look at it.

Comment: [A pretty similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632969/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-row-which-is-updated)

Answer (score 1):

You can it easy do with XOR ^ . you can give the operand in any system like 1,2,4,8..., for bit 0,1,2,3 OR  b'1', b'10', b'100'. Each bit is set was inverted.

In you Sample is the operand 128 or b'100000000'

**SAMPLE**

```
SELECT  b'1110111110' ^ 1 , b'1110111111' ^ 1 ;
SELECT  b'1110111110' ^ 128 , b'1100111111' ^ 128 ;
```

**If you want to see it as BITs**

```
SELECT  BIN( b'1110111110' ^ 1   ), BIN( b'1110111111' ^ 1   );
SELECT  BIN( b'1110111110' ^ 128 ), BIN( b'1100111111' ^ 128 );
```