# Flipping the value of BIT data type and make it 1 for NULL value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
// numbers
+---------+------------+
|    id   |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |   bit(1)   |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1          |
| 2       | 1          |
| 3       | 0          |
| 4       | NULL       |
+---------+------------+
```

And here is my query:

```
UPDATE numbers SET numb = numb ^ b'1';
```

And here is **current output:**

```
// numbers
+---------+------------+
|    id   |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |   bit(1)   |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 0          |
| 2       | 0          |
| 3       | 1          |
| 4       | NULL       |
+---------+------------+
```

And here is **expected output:**

```
// numbers
+---------+------------+
|    id   |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |   bit(1)   |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 0          |
| 2       | 0          |
| 3       | 1          |
| 4       | 1          |
+---------+------------+
```

As you see, All I'm trying to do is making `1` the result of `NULL ^ b'1'`. *(current result is `NULL`)*. How can I do that?

Comment: Try `UPDATE numbers SET numb = IFNULL(numb, 0) ^ b'1';`.

Comment: @wchiquito Hmm, not bad. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task combines two problems:

- Flipping a bit, and
- Dealing with `NULL`

You can combine [bit-toggling solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37073289/335858) from one of your other Q&As with `IFNULL` for an easy-to-read solution:

```
UPDATE numbers SET numb = IFNULL(numb ^ b'1', 1)
```

This is a nearly word-for-word translation of your question:

- "flip the value of bit" - `numb ^ b'1'`
- "or set `1` if it's `NULL`" - `IFNULL(..., 1)`

Comment: Clever ..! Or this `SET numb = IFNULL(numb , 0, numb) ^ b'1'`. Thank you. upvote

Comment: @stack That would work, too. However, it requires an extra mental step to understand that `NULL` is transformed to `1`, because the results of `IFNULL` are combined with XOR `^` operation with `1`.